# Calculate height of banner based on width

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have a banner slider that I am forcing 100% width. The problem is that when it loads, the first slide does not show (on chrome at least), I have to wait for the second slide to 'slide' in..then everything pushes down and looks as it should. If I set a fixed height it works fine, but my resolution is 1900 and different resolution screens would look bad with one locked in height.

I was wondering if there is a way I could calculate the visitors resolution and the banner dimensions to figure out the appropriate height based on the 100% width on load.

The beta url is http://www.can-do.org/beta/
(again, I think it works ok with IE, I only see it in Chrome/firefox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible to do this with CSS alone. The problem with @media rules is that you'd need one for each pixel width, which isn't viable. So you could try this instead:

Firstly, change the wrapper div here:

```
<div align="center">
```

to this

```
<div class="pluswrap">
```

Then, add these styles to your CSS file:

```
.pluswrap {
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 30%;
height: 0;
position: relative;
}
```

The slideshow height is always 30% of the width, so the 30% bottom padding is set to keep the container div open to that dimension at any screen size.

(I can't really text this properly remotely, but it's worth a try. It did seem to work, but I can't refresh the page and see what happen on page load, because the temporary styles get wiped. Would be keen to know if it worked, though.)

Comment: Ralph, I appreciate the feedback. I implemented this and it did indeed set the appropriate height, but the images did not load. Everything looked as it should but the banner was white until it slid in as before. THEN I applied that same class to the div that actually loads the banner itself...and I THINk it's working. (hard to tell sometimes with cache, but I've cleared it and I think it's working.) Please feel free to confirm http://www.can-do.org/beta

Comment: Looks great to me now. Well done. I'm glad I helped you find the solution. Unfortunately, it's hard to test a solution remotely that requires a page refresh (without recreating the whole page, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

Change your banner size using CSS code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #your_baner_image_id {width:000px;height:000px;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    #your_baner_image_id {width:000px;height:000px;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
    #your_baner_image_id {width:000px;height:000px;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 959px) {
    #your_baner_image_id {width:000px;height:000px;}
}
```

Comment: Paulius, I appreciate you taking the time to share this with me. I ended up using Ralph's idea below but like what you posted so I copied and saved it for future use on other projects. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Jquery, you can get user Resolution by:

```
$(window).width();
$(window).height();
```

example:

```
$(function(){
    var w = $(window).width();
    $('your-banner').css('height',w*30%);//<--this will set banner height 30% of screen width
});
```

Comment: Charlie, I appreciate you taking the time to help out on this. I get what you are doing here. I like it and I've saved it for other projects. Currently it looks like Ralph's css suggestion worked so I'll be using it. Thanks Again!